# ovirt iso upload not visible in webgui

Tags: linux, centos, virtualization, nfs

I recently set up an ovirt host with an [self hosted engine](http://www.ovirt.org/develop/release-management/features/engine/self-hosted-engine/). I use nfs shares as a storage backend (freenas). The setup went through perfectly and I was able to access the webgui. Everything seems to work fine, except the iso upload. 
After uploading an iso (debian-8.4.0-amd64-netinst.iso) using the ovirt-iso-uploader I wanted to setup a VM. Sadly, I was not able to choose an iso to attach (Attach CD). Also the image tab under the iso storage shows "No items to display" even after pressing the refresh button.
After rebooting the engine, putting the iso domain to maintenance, detach, attach again, enable and upload an other image, I got the same result.

After searching a bit the logs, I could find the following in vdsm.log:

```
jsonrpc.Executor/1::INFO::2016-08-16 09:12:51,066::logUtils::51::dispatcher::(wrapper) Run and protect: getFileStats, Return response: {'fileStats': {u'debian-8.2.0-amd64-netinst.iso': {'status': 469, 'ctime': '1471271972.0', 'size': '258998272'}, u'debian-8.4.0-amd64-netinst.iso': {'status': 469, 'ctime': '1471263076.0', 'size': '258998272'}}}
```

This appears each time I try to list the images in the webgui.
I can also find the mounted path and files on the hypervisor:

```
-rw-r-----. 1 root root 258998272 Aug 15 14:11 /rhev/data-center/mnt/hades.gwitter.ch:_mnt_Master_iso/a93e3450-42e1-494b-a3bc-12756f16ed29/images/11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111/debian-8.4.0-amd64-netinst.iso
```

I really do not know, if I am hitting a bug or if I just missed something.

Additional infos:
I used centos7 as abase os and the package ovirt-engine-appliance-3.6-20160623.1.el7.centos.noarch to install the engine.
The iso domain was created during the hosted-egine setup on the same nfs host as the hosted-engine is placed.
oVirt Engine Version: 3.6.6.2-1.el7.centos

Answer (score 1):

I just found my issue!
The iso images folder needs to be owned by 36:36 (user vdsm group kvm).
Just use chown on your nfs server to adjust your permissions:

```
chown -R 36:36 a93e3450-42e1-494b-a3bc-12756f16ed29/images/11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111
```

Also newly uploaded images will be shown in the webgui now.